# C# Syntax error when creating a query with OleDbParamater

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, syntax-error, oledbcommand

I am using `OleDbParameter` to build an `OleDbCommand` to `INSERT` a record into `MS Access`. But I get Syntax Error when I am executing the statement. If anyone can see what is preventing the query successfully executing it would be a huge help.

This is my code:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Customer (customerID, date, time, telephone, fax,"
    + "name, sourceAddress, destAddress, via1, via2, via3,"
    + "priority, ourReference) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

OleDbCommand oleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, oleDbConnection);

OleDbParameter customerID = new OleDbParameter();
OleDbParameter date = new OleDbParameter();
OleDbParameter time = new OleDbParameter();
OleDbParameter telephone = new OleDbParameter();
OleDbParameter fax = new OleDbParameter();
OleDbParameter name = new OleDbParameter();
OleDbParameter sourceAddress = new OleDbParameter();
OleDbParameter destAddress = new OleDbParameter();
OleDbParameter via1 = new OleDbParameter();
OleDbParameter via2 = new OleDbParameter();
OleDbParameter via3 = new OleDbParameter();
OleDbParameter priority = new OleDbParameter();
OleDbParameter ourReference = new OleDbParameter();

oleDbCommand.Parameters.Add(customerID);
oleDbCommand.Parameters.Add(date);
oleDbCommand.Parameters.Add(time);
oleDbCommand.Parameters.Add(telephone);
oleDbCommand.Parameters.Add(fax);
oleDbCommand.Parameters.Add(name);
oleDbCommand.Parameters.Add(sourceAddress);
oleDbCommand.Parameters.Add(destAddress);
oleDbCommand.Parameters.Add(via1);
oleDbCommand.Parameters.Add(via2);
oleDbCommand.Parameters.Add(via3);
oleDbCommand.Parameters.Add(priority);
oleDbCommand.Parameters.Add(ourReference);

customerID.Value = 4;
date.Value = "01/01/01";
time.Value = "01:01:01";
telephone.Value = 01010101;
fax.Value = 01010101;
name.Value = "test 4";
sourceAddress.Value = "test 4 source address";
destAddress.Value = "test 4 dest address";
via1.Value = "test 4 via 1";
via2.Value = "test 4 via 2";
via3.Value = "test 4 via 3";
priority.Value = 1;
ourReference.Value = "test 4 ref";

MessageBox.Show(oleDbCommand.CommandText.ToString());

OleDbDataAdapter oleDbDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(oleDbCommand);

oleDbCommand.CommandText = query;

oleDbConnection.Open();

oleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Given that it's a syntax error, it would really help if you'd show us the query instead of just the parameters.

Comment: sorry i forgot about the most important part, I edited it into the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fields `date` and `time` are [reserved words for JET/Access](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx), so you should encapsulate them in square brackets. (this is the real origin of the Syntax Error message)

```
"INSERT INTO Customer (customerID, [date], [time], telephone, fax, name, " + 
"sourceAddress, destAddress, via1, via2, via3," + "priority, ourReference) VALUES " + 
"(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Of course the number of parameters should match. (12 placeholder vs 13 fields/parameters, add another placeholder ?), but this will give another error message, not the syntax error stated

Comment: Thanks Steve, hole in one! the query now inserts into the database :)

Answer (score 1):

You have 13 parameters, but only 12 ?

Comment: I added another ?, so now I have 13. But I am still getting the error `Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement`

Is there a way of displaying the sql command that is being executed
to get more clues? `oleDbCommand.CommandText.ToString()` displays:

`INSERT INTO Customer (customerID, date, time, telephone, fax, name, sourceAddress, destAddress, via1, via2, via3,priority, ourReference) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

which isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned your parameters are out of sync with your place holders, however, if your CustomerID is an autonumber then you can omit it from both the sql and the parameter list.